In which US states are hush money payments illegal?
I was just reading something from the New Yorker magazine which stated:

“Paying hush money is not a crime under New York state law,” Mark
Pomerantz, a lawyer who worked in the D.A.’s office, wrote, in “People
vs. Donald Trump,” an insider account of the office’s investigation of
the former President..

So my question is, in which US state(s) is paying hush money considered illegal?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

"Hush money" is just tabloid-speak for a non-disclosure agreement, which is generally legal throughout the United States -- or, for the money paid in exchange for the non-disclosure agreement.
There are some exceptions, like the Ending Forced Arbitration of Sexual Assault and Sexual Harassment Act, which limits the enforceability of NDAs regarding sexual harassment.
And while an NDA may limit you from voluntarily providing information to the police, it cannot limit you from answering truthfully when under oath, i.e., when you are ordered to answer by a court or a subpoena issued by a court.

Isn't the distinction that 'hush money ' is money paid in exchange for an NDA, rather than an NDA in general? I was under an NDA a while back but wasn't paid for it, so it wouldn't count as hush money. (Which doesn't change the fact that paying someone to sign an NDA remains legal as well, of course.)

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Good point. There has to be some kind of consideration given in exchange for the NDA, whether it's money, a job opportunity, or simply keeping the job you have. Every enforceable NDA must involve some kind of "hush consideration", otherwise it's not a contract.

@NuclearHoagie The difference is usually that non-disclosure tends to be necessay for the exchange. E.g. exployees would be working against the interests of their employer if they divulge proprietary information to competitors. It's called "hush money" when the only consideration is money for silence.

@Barmar I suppose there's an element of timing - an NDA could come before or after the information is disclosed, although in practice most people would try to get it beforehand. "Hush money," on the other hand, implies the information is already known by the other party - you wouldn't pay someone hush money and then tell them the secret you want them to keep quiet.

@NuclearHoagie That's usually true for normal business-oriented NDAs. But sometimes NDAs occur after the fact, like when Fox News paid off harassment victims in exchange for them signing NDAs so they won't reveal what happened to the media.

Interesting. Could I get around an NDA that I wanted to break without penalty by asking to be put under oath and have someone ask me relevant questions until they work out what I can't say?

Strictly speaking, an NDA cannot prevent you from testifying when you are ordered by a court or a subpoena issued by a court, to do so, and while this almost always happens while you are under oath, the fact that the statement is made under oath, per se, is not actually relevant.

Some other exceptions (mostly for whistleblowing) in the federal Defend Trade Secrets Act. https://www.congress.gov/bill/114th-congress/senate-bill/1890/text which are codified at 18 U.S.C. § 1833. https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1833

I would argue that 'non-disclosure agreement' is legal speak for 'hushmoney'

"And while an NDA may limit you from voluntarily providing information to the police, it cannot limit you from answering truthfully when under oath." Does that mean that you cannot be sued or sanctioned for breaking an NDA if you were forced to do so under oath?

Assuming you've been compelled to testify, yes, that's generally going to be correct.

""Hush money" is just tabloid-speak for a non-disclosure agreement" - no, it's tabloid-speak specifically for a non-disclosure agreement whose purpose is to conceal wrongdoing. Ordinary employment as any kind of knowledge worker often involves NDAs but their purpose (at least ostensibly!) is to protect trade secrets and IP, not to conceal wrongdoing, and this distinguishes these typical NDAs from "hush money". Paying me not to reveal the secret chemical process used to make your product and paying me not to reveal that it's made by slaves are both NDAs but only the latter is hush money.

“Hush money” can be paying a blackmailer, paying for inconvenient facts to be not made public, or paying for evidence of crimes being kept secret. I’m sure that’s treated differently.

@gnasher729 Which one are you saying is treated differently? Paying a blackmailer is generally legal, and in most cases, I suspect paying for evidence of crmes to be kept secret is also legal. "Paying for inconvenient facts not to be made public" is basically the definition of an NDA, and the situation that I think OP is actually asking about.
